# jPlayer is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have multiple play list items in my page. When click on this  play buttons only the first item playing.This is my js code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
    $(".tapePlay").click(function() { 


        var playListId  =  $(this).attr('rel');
        var playListId  = parseInt(playListId);

        myPlaylist.play(playListId);
    });
```

Comment: Did you get your solution on Zip archive question? Why you deleted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try a return false in your click function, may it will solve your issue.